# Вводное предложение с союзом КАК между подлежащим и сказуемым

Tags: запятые, тире, вводные-слова, обороты-с-как

*Возведение дополнительных компартиментов, **как мы успели увидеть** – расхожая практика* (авторский вариант).

Вроде бы надо обособить вводное предложение с двух сторон, то есть поставить еще одну запятую. Но по правилам при наличии вводного слова между подлежащим и сказуемым **не ставится тире**.

Получаются три варианта: (1) только две запятые, (2) две запятые и тире, а еще  (3) два тире без запятых.

**Хотя бы одно тире нужно** (пауза явно присутствует, части предложения надо разделить). Кстати, Розенталь говорит, что вводное слово обычно относится ко второй части, а при варианте (2) получается, что к первой.

Что-то очень много вопросов для довольно простой конструкции, **а есть ли правило и примеры?**

Примечание. ***Компартимент*** (франц. compartiment, от лат. соmраrаrе — соединять). В архитектуре — часть внутренних помещений, соединенных в анфиладу и выделенных на фасаде здания отдельным объемом.

Comment: И ещё вариант - переставить оборот после тире, что лучше.

Comment: Такой вариант не рассматривается, так как к тексту не имеет отношения. Я же решаю конкретную задачу.

Comment: При этом меняется не текст, а только знаки: запятую заменяем на тире, а тире - на запятую.

Comment: Будьте добры, приводите текст исправленного предложения, а не ваши описания его. Я считаю это небрежностью по отношению к людям, которые читают ваши сообщения. Если вам не трудно, пожалуйста. Это касается и ваших ответов, в которых практически никогда не дается исправленный текст. Угадывать, где и что, - это довольно утомительно.

Comment: Говорю, что ещё один вариант (изменены только знаки): *Возведение дополнительных компартиментов – как мы успели увидеть, расхожая практика.*

Comment: Нет, не подходит. Пауза явно делается перед сказуемым.

Comment: Тоже вам лайк поставлю. Так подумал, что вопрос оказался полезен.

Comment: Спасибо, спасибо...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случаях с вводным словом без тире на первую часть не падает логическое ударение. Не делается, как говорит Розенталь, "логическое или интонационное членение предложения". То есть не задумывается чёткое определение понятия. А здесь у нас некий гибрид – первая часть без ударения, но тире есть. Попробуем разобраться.

Вижу разницу в логических ударениях (соответственно, разная интонация и прочтение):

1) *Возведение дополнительных компартимЕнтов, как мы успели увидеть, – расхОжая практика.*

2) *Возведение дополнительных компартиментов, как мы успели увидеть, расхОжая практика.*
Предложение сильно распространённое. Оно так не читается. У Розенталя примеры без тире короткие.

3) *Возведение дополнительных компартиментов, как мы успели увИдеть – расхОжая практика.*
Читается удобнее. Вместо запятой употреблено интонационное тире. Случай просто поразительный.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я думаю, что читается  по первому варианту, я этот вариант и оставила.  А правило? Я решила приравнять вводное придаточное к обычным определительным предложениям,  для них запятая перед тире ставится. И так как наши решения совпали,  я ставлю два лайка вашему ответу (или всё-таки два плюсика?).

Comment: Лайк и галочку (два лайка с одного аккаунта нельзя поставить). Создатели сайта называют это *upvote* [голос "за"] (отличие от лайка в том, что лайки в форме сердечек и лайки и дизлайки отделены) и *accepted as the best* (принят [можно перевести как "признан"] как лучший). Аж не верится, что такое возможно (первый мой ответ, который вы приняли). Здесь комбинация моментов из разных правил. Третий вариант целесообразен, если раньше обсуждали это понятие (его не обязательно подчёркивать логически). А раз они успели увидеть, то точно обсуждали. А что, это ваше предложение (раз вы оставили вариант)?

Comment: Я вас просто проверяю (вернее, ваш профиль, а это был пароль для проверки). Текст же не мой, я его редактирую.

Comment: Ничего не понял. Какой такой пароль и что за проверка?

Comment: Значит, вы не прошли проверку, если ничего не поняли.

Comment: Ничего себе конспирация! А можно намёк?

Comment: Нельзя.  Не понимаете, что такое пароль?  Просто вы не тот, за кого я вас принимала,

Comment: Не тот в хорошем смысле? Пароль к чему?

Comment: oleedd, теперь уж точно ничего не скажу. Не тот - в нейтральном смысле. Всё, вопрос закрыт.